# Read and Edit Excel in GWT Client Code

Tags: gwt, apache-poi, xlsx

I have a GWT application with server and client code. I want to read and display an Excel (.xslx) file from the user in the GUI without passing it to the server. Is it possible to do this with the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) or can't GWT compile all needed code from POI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side you will only be able to use this packages: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

You have to pass the excel to the server