# Apache POI to JS using GWT

Tags: javascript, java, apache, gwt, apache-poi

Has anyone ever managed to transcribe [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) from Java to JS using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/)? I am looking for any pointers/tutorials.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/) - what are you trying to achieve? Additionally, what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and Edit Excel in GWT Client Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649868/read-and-edit-excel-in-gwt-client-code)

Answer (score 0):

No, I haven't found one and I am pretty sure it is not feasible.